# Hosting my own website via XAMPP?

Tags: apache, localhost, hosting

Basically what I am trying to understand is if I purchase a domain called www.example.com, can  I somehow create the website for that domain and host it through my own computer via XAMPP? Or do I need to purchase hosting from some where else such as HostGator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host on your computer:

1. Have an IP Public
2. Setting your server : use Linux (Cent OS, Red Hat, etc) or Windows server
3. And other configuration

Recomended to buy a service on hosting service, like Hostgator, hostmonster, bluehost, or etc.
you will get instant and no need to setting.